# How to remove trailing whitespaces from string in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2

In my case all the strings are single-worded and the trailing whitespaces from the strings need to be removed, *e.g.*, `'hello '`→ `'hello'`; `'hello           '`→ `'hello'`.

One approach could be using split, *i.e*,

```
{% if ' ' in word %}
  {% set word = word.split(' ')[0] %}
{% endif %}
```

This works since the strings are one-worded. I am quite sure there must be a better approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Silly me! It is `.strip()`, *i.e.*, `'hello     '.strip()`.

Answer (score 11):

It's not `.strip()` ... it's `| trim` . Such as `{{ some_variable_string_name | trim }}`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply iterate though your list and remove the trailing spaces. by default split() function has whitespaces.

```
data=['hello ','hello   ',...]
new_data=[]
for i in data:
  new_data.append(i.split())
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured out. Is there any better approach in Jinja2?